# Get day name in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

How get day name in below example:

```
SELECT
    day   AS return,
    day   AS display,
    ''   AS day_name
FROM
    (
        WITH temp ( col ) AS (
            SELECT
                to_date(2, 'mm') --2 is February
            FROM
                dual
        )
        SELECT
            to_number(to_char(col + level - 1, 'dd')) day
        FROM
            temp
        CONNECT BY
            level <= last_day(col) - col + 1
        ORDER BY
            day
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need the following:

```
SELECT
    day   AS return,
    day   AS display,
    day_name  AS day_name
FROM
    (
        WITH temp ( col ) AS (
            SELECT
                to_date(2, 'mm') --2 is February
            FROM
                dual
        )
        SELECT
            to_number(to_char(col + level - 1, 'dd')) day,
            to_char(col + level - 1, 'DAY') as day_name     /* day/DAY/Day for lower/upper case*/
        FROM
            temp
        CONNECT BY
            level <= last_day(col) - col + 1
        ORDER BY
            day
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

> How get day name

Use:

```
TO_CHAR( day, 'fmDAY' )
```

*(The `fm` format model will strip the trailing whitespace that would otherwise be output as `TO_CHAR( date_value, 'DAY' )` will right-pad the day names with whitespaces so that they all have the same length as the longest day-name.)*

So:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM day ) AS return,
       EXTRACT( DAY FROM day ) AS display,
       TO_CHAR( day, 'fmDAY' ) AS day_name
FROM (
  WITH temp ( col ) AS (
    SELECT to_date(2, 'mm') --2 is February
    FROM   dual
  )
  SELECT col + level - 1 AS day
  FROM   temp
  CONNECT BY level <= last_day(col) - col + 1
  ORDER BY day
)
```

Which, outputs:

> ```
> RETURN | DISPLAY | DAY_NAME 
> -----: | ------: | :--------
>      1 |       1 | MONDAY   
>      2 |       2 | TUESDAY  
>      3 |       3 | WEDNESDAY
>      4 |       4 | THURSDAY 
>      5 |       5 | FRIDAY   
>      6 |       6 | SATURDAY 
>      7 |       7 | SUNDAY   
>      8 |       8 | MONDAY   
>      9 |       9 | TUESDAY  
>     10 |      10 | WEDNESDAY
>     11 |      11 | THURSDAY 
>     12 |      12 | FRIDAY   
>     13 |      13 | SATURDAY 
>     14 |      14 | SUNDAY   
>     15 |      15 | MONDAY   
>     16 |      16 | TUESDAY  
>     17 |      17 | WEDNESDAY
>     18 |      18 | THURSDAY 
>     19 |      19 | FRIDAY   
>     20 |      20 | SATURDAY 
>     21 |      21 | SUNDAY   
>     22 |      22 | MONDAY   
>     23 |      23 | TUESDAY  
>     24 |      24 | WEDNESDAY
>     25 |      25 | THURSDAY 
>     26 |      26 | FRIDAY   
>     27 |      27 | SATURDAY 
>     28 |      28 | SUNDAY
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=14455f6e12f5df5e5895404d4991a776)*

Answer (score 0):

While selecting day number you can select day name also **to_char(col+level-1,'day')** .
Please use below query:

```
SELECT
    day   AS return,
    day   AS display,
    day_name
FROM
    (
        WITH temp ( col ) AS (
            SELECT
                to_date(2, 'mm') --2 is February
            FROM
                dual
        )
        SELECT
            to_number(to_char(col + level - 1, 'dd')) day ,to_char(col+level-1,'day') day_name
        FROM
            temp
        CONNECT BY
            level <= last_day(col) - col + 1
        ORDER BY
            day
    )
```